# Return RedirectToAction in MVC using async & await

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I want to return an action using Async and await functionality in dot net 4.5.
I have used the following code.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DisplayDashboard()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (true)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
            }
        });            
    }
```

Its giving following error,
"Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Action' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type".

Can anybody please suggest me how to perform RedirectToAction using Task.

Comment: What do you mean _return view **and** redirect to action_? (you can't do both)

Comment: Beware that using `Task.Run` in ASP.NET hurts your performance as you'll only be switching from one thread pool thread to another and back - 2 useless thread switches.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> DisplayDashboard()
    {
        return await Task.Run<ActionResult>(() =>
        {
            if (true)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Index");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the if(true) condition?

Comment: @Amol possibly knows the purpose :)

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need this code async? If all you need is to make this method return a Task to satisfy some interface requirement, then use:

```
public Task<ActionResult> DisplayDashboard()
{
        ActionResult result;
        if (true)
        {
            result = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            result = View("Index");
        }
        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
```

Task.Run() would actually use a different thread to the code you pass into it.  It doesn't seem that you need to do that here.

Comment: My code is too large to put it here. I have a requirement in which I have to either redirect to action or return view using Task. That is why I have to use async

Comment: In my case, I'm calling `HttpClient` and since the gosh dang little F'er no longer allows anything but `async` calls, my whole frick'en graph has to be async now. (FACE-frick'en-PALM)

Answer (score 0):

This is old but is the first result returned from Google so worth correcting. The return from RedirectToAction() or View() cannot be continued so why await the results. Therefore there is no need to artificially Task.Run() only to await it. The async keyword will already lift any returns into a Task. The resulting code is cleaner.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DisplayDashboard()
{
    if (true)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```